# receive delivery list of send mail in django

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, email-confirmation

I want use `send_mass_mail()` in `django` and then want receive list of delivery mail

list with email address and problem for failed or delivered ok status

how i can make this modules ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List of delivered emails is outside of the scope of Django, which is a web framework and not a replacement for services like Mailchimp.

Comment: in net how we can find delivered mail?

Comment: @Efazati: E.g. by placing inside it 1x1 image with unique name and tracking if/when somebody fetches that image. Or by using links with unique names. There are also so called return receipts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_receipt; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_tracking. Also, you may want to handle rejected emails. As you can see this is a very broad topic.